# issue in making kendo ui window responsive

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

i am working on kendo ui controls in asp.net mvc4.
i have an issue to make kendo ui window responsive.
Is there any way to make it responsive,i google it but not find any specific solution.any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Window's width and height in percent and then the widget will resize, depending on the browser window's size (but only until the user resizes the Window manually). Alternatively, use the browser's `window.resize` event to set a new Window dimensions with the `setOptions` method.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window#configuration-width

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window#methods-setOptions